# Applescript folder action to add new files to iTunes playlist

Tags: applescript, dropbox, itunes

I am trying to create an applescript for a dropbox folder so that when a new file is added to the folder, it will automatically add that file to a particular playlist in iTunes (the goal being to be able to update multiple computers' playlists remotely by just adding one file to one dropbox folder.)

The applescript works with the exception of adding the file into the iTunes playlist. It is a bit tricky to debug because it is a folder action so it cannot be run in script editor. I have been using display dialog to try to understand what is happening but the dialogs show what looks like correct information to me so I am stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried using a POSIX path instead, I have tried setting the item as an alias, as a string, I've tried setting the item to another variable with "\"" & item & "\""

```
set playlistToUpdate to "Public News Service"

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    set filesAdded to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theNewItems
        set thisItem to item i of theNewItems as alias
        tell application "iTunes"
            launch
            delay 2
            display dialog thisItem
            add thisItem to playlist playlistToUpdate
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 0):

A folder action will fail silently unless you do something like use a `try` statement with an alert dialog.  In your posted example, there will be an error in using `display dialog` with an alias instead of first coercing it to a string.

I've found that by breaking the functionality out into its own handler(s) and adding `run` and `open` handlers, the script can be tested and run from the **Script Editor** or as an applet/droplet, in addition to being used as a folder action, for example:

```
property playlistToUpdate : "Public News Service"

on run -- applet or from the Script Editor
    doStuff for (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
end run

on open droppedItems -- droplet
    doStuff for droppedItems
end open

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems -- folder action
    doStuff for theNewItems
end adding folder items to

to doStuff for someItems -- the main stuff
    set filesAdded to {}
    repeat with anItem in someItems
        tell application "iTunes"
            launch
            delay 2
            display dialog (anItem as text)
            add anItem to playlist playlistToUpdate
        end tell
    end repeat
end doStuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Thats definitely a step up from how I've been trying to debug. Unfortunately, I still can't figure out whats wrong with the applescript...

Comment: It works for me with a regular folder, is the folder and action set up in the `Folder Actions Setup...`?

Comment: It is set up in Folder Actions Setup. Thats weird -- for me, it will launch iTunes but it will not add the file to the playlist. Could it be related to the folder being inside of a Dropbox folder maybe? Whats crazy is that this works:

`code` set playlistToUpdate to "Public News Service"
set itemToAdd to "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:Dropbox (Wave Farm):WGXC Studio Audio:Public News Service:Mamas 96 K Master 3.24 RUNAWAY MOON.mp3" as alias

tell application "iTunes"
 launch
 
 add itemToAdd to playlist playlistToUpdate
 
end tell
`code`

but not when its attached to a folder...

Comment: Dropbox is supposed to work like a folder - does it work if you attach it to a regular folder?